# How to add Framework containing pods into another project

Tags: ios, swift, mqtt, ios-frameworks

I am facing a problem and searched for it a lot but did not found any solution.

I had created a **Swift framework** that uses **MQTTKit"** that I added to my Framework using `CocoaPods`.

Now I had created a sample app that will use the above framework.

Then I created a workspace and added the xcodeproj file of `framework` as well as sample app to the workspace.

But now I am not able to use that `framework` in my sample app.

I am getting the error **No such module MQTTKit** inside my `framework`.

However there is no error in the `framework` if I `build` it separately?

So is there is any problem with the `pods` or something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey I found another way of doing the above thing.
What we can do is instead of using cocoapods we can add the frameworks manually in our own framework.
Since cocoa pods is not playing well with embedded framework as mentioned in the following link.
http://samwize.com/2015/01/26/projects-workspace-embedded-framework-and-cocoapods/.
So I did the same things added the frameworks manually in my framework then I added the framework as a subproject in my app.
Now it is working fine.

Answer (score 3):

If you're using multiple Xcode Projects in a single Workspace, you should use pod targets like this:

```
platform :ios, '9.0'
inhibit_all_warnings!
use_frameworks!

target "MyApp" do
  xcodeproj 'MyApp'
  pod 'MQTTKit'

  target "SampleApp" do
    xcodeproj 'SampleApp'
    inherit! :search_paths
    pod 'MQTTKit'
  end
end
```

To learn more, refer to Cocoapods [Podfile Syntax Reference](https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podfile.html#podfile)

Comment: Thank RodolfoAntonici for the answer! May be rewrite the framework into a pod is easier to solve the dependency problem?

Answer (score 0):

I know it's late answer, but maybe it will help someone.

I had the same problem when I wanted to use my framework project embedded into a demo project so I could test framework during development.

My framework was using cocoapods to download its dependencies, so if you want to use it as a subproject, you have to put everything in demo project: framework project, framework pods projects, workspace of framework project.

So demo project tree would look like this:

```
DemoApp project
    --- framework.xcodeproj
    --- pods.xcodeproj (the one from the framework project)
    --- framework.xcworkspace
```